# React state with setState value is undefined in functional component custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-ref

My problem is the next: I want to encapsulate a functional component out of the App main component, the problem is that having the State its own values, in the functional component, which calls a custom hook, is undefined.
I cannot understand why is this happening, taking into account that state is being invoked with useState hook.

The code is the next:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    mathOp: '',
    result: [400],
    secondNumber: [5],
});

const stateRef = useRef(state);

const useHookWithRefCallback = ({state, setState, stateRef}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffectCallback");
        console.log(state);
        stateRef.current.mathOp = '';
        stateRef.current.result = [''];
        stateRef.current.secondNumber = [''];
        setState({
            ...stateRef,
            result: stateRef.current.result,
            secondNumber: stateRef.current.secondNumber,
            mathOp: stateRef.current.mathOp,
        });
    }, [setState, stateRef]);
};

const useClear = useHookWithRefCallback({ state, setState, stateRef });

const Clear = ({ state, setState, stateRef }) => {
    console.log({state});
    console.log({stateRef});
    return <button onClick={useClear}>Clear</button>;
};
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where exactly value is `undefined`? at what moment?

Comment: Hi Skyboyer. Right now, my code is done to be executed as soon as Clear Component in rendered, the custom hook in working properly when it comes to being executed, but the state and stateRef variables are undefined. It's something that I cannot achieve to understand.

Comment: Skyboyer, i just wanna tell you that after some tests i can say that useRef is not working as I did expected. I mean, once i call const stateRef = useRef(state); in the App main component, if i console.log() it , it's undefined. I cannot understand why

Comment: My problem is right now solved by myself. The problem was the scope access when it comes to the stateRef current values, thank you anyway. Kind regards, blackout.